# Creating a templete with xlsxwriter in django webframework

Tags: python, django, spreadsheet, xlsxwriter

I'm new to django and still trying to figure out logic. I watched a bunch of videos and I know how to create those examples but I'm not quite there. I'll explain what I want and maybe someone can explain to me a logic how to do, yes?

I created an app and inside an app I connected urls, settings, html and I have working site. Now I want to input data in django website, django to pass data to xlsxwriter script to create xlsx document, and to pass that document to user to download.

My logic: What I need now, is to create some kind forms (but not for registered users, it can use anyone who uses a website) to input data. Which forms are best? Than I need to pass () that data to function that are in views that will get an arguments from html page through some kind of forms, create document, and pass that to download button.